# How can I mute TextToSpeech?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, google-text-to-speech

I want the user to be able to turn off the volume of TextToSpeech. I have a button to to this. At the minute I am shutting down the TTS and creating new instance every time the user turns it back on which seems a complete round about way of doing it.

Is there a more efficient way to do this I see no default methods to achieve this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to create a bundle and pass this as a third parameter. In the budle you should use `params.putFloat(KEY_PARAM_VOLUME, 0.0f);` The code explains it better:

```
private Bundle params;

public TextToSpeechHelper(Context context) {
    mTTS = new TextToSpeech(context, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                int result = mTTS.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);
                params = new Bundle();

                if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                    Log.e("TTS", "Language not supported");
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("TTS", "Initialization failed");
            }
        }
    });
}

public void speakThis(String whatToSay){
    String speech = whatToSay;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mTTS.speak(speech,TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, params, null);
    } else {
        mTTS.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
    }
}

public void mute() {

    params.putFloat(KEY_PARAM_VOLUME, 0.0f);

}

public void soundOn() {

    params.putFloat(KEY_PARAM_VOLUME, 1.0f);

}
```